# SSL connection error on a valid HTTPS request

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I am not sure why in Chrome or IE, I cannot see the HTTPS request to my self signed certificate application.

1. Error in Chrome
   [image]
2. Running the node app (http and https ports are listening)
   [image]
3. curl respond to the https request
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the certificate itself. I created a new certificate using `openssl` and this time I made sure to **issue to localhost**.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

delete google chrome https cache

link: chrome://net-internals/#hsts

Delete domain security policies
Domain: localhost delete

this will solve the ssl problem